# How to add a new table column?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

This is my project for Android. I've tried to create a new table column: KEY_EXAMPLE. But it doesn't work. I'll put my code below and I would like to fix this. Can someone help me, please? It's very important. I'm a newbie. The KEY_EXAMPLE doesn't work. This is my code and what I'm trying to do this workout.

DictionaryDatabase.Java

```
public class DictionaryDatabase {
private static final String TAG = "DictionaryDatabase";

public static final String KEY_WORD = SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1;
public static final String KEY_DEFINITION = SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_2;
public static final String KEY_EXAMPLE = SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_EXTRA_DATA;

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "dictionary";
private static final String FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE = "FTSdictionary";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;

private final DictionaryOpenHelper mDatabaseOpenHelper;
private static final HashMap<String,String> mColumnMap = buildColumnMap();

public DictionaryDatabase(Context context) {
    mDatabaseOpenHelper = new DictionaryOpenHelper(context);
}

private static HashMap<String,String> buildColumnMap() {
    HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
    map.put(KEY_WORD, KEY_WORD);
    map.put(KEY_DEFINITION, KEY_DEFINITION);
    map.put(KEY_EXAMPLE, KEY_EXAMPLE);
    map.put(BaseColumns._ID, "rowid AS " +
            BaseColumns._ID);
    map.put(SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA_ID, "rowid AS " +
            SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA_ID);
    map.put(SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_SHORTCUT_ID, "rowid AS " +
            SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_SHORTCUT_ID);
    return map;
}

public Cursor getWord(String rowId, String[] columns) {
    String selection = "rowid = ?";
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {rowId};

    return query(selection, selectionArgs, columns);

}

public Cursor getWordMatches(String query, String[] columns) {
    String selection = KEY_WORD + " MATCH ?";
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {query+"*"};

    return query(selection, selectionArgs, columns);

}

private Cursor query(String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String[] columns) {

    SQLiteQueryBuilder builder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    builder.setTables(FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE);
    builder.setProjectionMap(mColumnMap);

    Cursor cursor = builder.query(mDatabaseOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(),
            columns, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);

    if (cursor == null) {
        return null;
    } else if (!cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        cursor.close();
        return null;
    }
    return cursor;
}

private static class DictionaryOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private final Context mHelperContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;

    private static final String FTS_TABLE_CREATE =
                "CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE " + FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE +
                " USING fts3 (" +
                KEY_WORD + ", " +
                KEY_DEFINITION + 
                KEY_EXAMPLE + ");";

    DictionaryOpenHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        mHelperContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        mDatabase = db;
        mDatabase.execSQL(FTS_TABLE_CREATE);
        loadDictionary();
    }

    private void loadDictionary() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    loadWords();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    private void loadWords() throws IOException {
        Log.d(TAG, "Loading words...");
        final Resources resources = mHelperContext.getResources();
        InputStream inputStream = resources.openRawResource(R.raw.definitions);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

        try {
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] strings = TextUtils.split(line, "-");
                if (strings.length < 2) continue;
                long id = addWord(strings[0].trim(), strings[1].trim(), strings[2].trim());
                if (id < 0) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "unable to add word: " + strings[0].trim());
                }
            }
        } finally {
            reader.close();
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "DONE loading words.");
    }


    public long addWord(String word, String definition, String example) {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(KEY_WORD, word);
        initialValues.put(KEY_DEFINITION, definition);
        initialValues.put(KEY_EXAMPLE, example);

        return mDatabase.insert(FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}

}
```

DictionaryProvider.Java

```
public class DictionaryProvider extends ContentProvider {
String TAG = "DictionaryProvider";

public static String AUTHORITY = "com.pesquisa.dicionario.searchabledict.DictionaryProvider";
public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY + "/dictionary");

public static final String WORDS_MIME_TYPE = ContentResolver.CURSOR_DIR_BASE_TYPE +
                                              "/vnd.pesquisa.dicionario.searchabledict";
public static final String DEFINITION_MIME_TYPE = ContentResolver.CURSOR_ITEM_BASE_TYPE +
                                                   "/vnd.pesquisa.dicionario.searchabledict";

private DictionaryDatabase mDictionary;

private static final int SEARCH_WORDS = 0;
private static final int GET_WORD = 1;
private static final int SEARCH_SUGGEST = 2;
private static final int REFRESH_SHORTCUT = 3;
private static final UriMatcher sURIMatcher = buildUriMatcher();

private static UriMatcher buildUriMatcher() {
    UriMatcher matcher =  new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
    matcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, "dictionary", SEARCH_WORDS);
    matcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, "dictionary/#", GET_WORD);
    matcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, SearchManager.SUGGEST_URI_PATH_QUERY, SEARCH_SUGGEST);
    matcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, SearchManager.SUGGEST_URI_PATH_QUERY + "/*", SEARCH_SUGGEST);

    matcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, SearchManager.SUGGEST_URI_PATH_SHORTCUT, REFRESH_SHORTCUT);
    matcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, SearchManager.SUGGEST_URI_PATH_SHORTCUT + "/*", REFRESH_SHORTCUT);
    return matcher;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreate() {
    mDictionary = new DictionaryDatabase(getContext());
    return true;
}

@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs,
                    String sortOrder) {

    switch (sURIMatcher.match(uri)) {
        case SEARCH_SUGGEST:
            if (selectionArgs == null) {
              throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                  "selectionArgs must be provided for the Uri: " + uri);
            }
            return getSuggestions(selectionArgs[0]);
        case SEARCH_WORDS:
            if (selectionArgs == null) {
              throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                  "selectionArgs must be provided for the Uri: " + uri);
            }
            return search(selectionArgs[0]);
        case GET_WORD:
            return getWord(uri);
        case REFRESH_SHORTCUT:
            return refreshShortcut(uri);
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown Uri: " + uri);
    }
}

private Cursor getSuggestions(String query) {
  query = query.toLowerCase();
  String[] columns = new String[] {
      BaseColumns._ID,
      DictionaryDatabase.KEY_WORD,
      SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA_ID};

  return mDictionary.getWordMatches(query, columns);
}

private Cursor search(String query) {
  query = query.toLowerCase();
  String[] columns = new String[] {
      BaseColumns._ID,
      DictionaryDatabase.KEY_WORD,
      DictionaryDatabase.KEY_DEFINITION,
      DictionaryDatabase.KEY_EXAMPLE};

  return mDictionary.getWordMatches(query, columns);
}

private Cursor getWord(Uri uri) {
  String rowId = uri.getLastPathSegment();
  String[] columns = new String[] {
      DictionaryDatabase.KEY_WORD,
      DictionaryDatabase.KEY_DEFINITION,
      DictionaryDatabase.KEY_EXAMPLE};

  return mDictionary.getWord(rowId, columns);
}

private Cursor refreshShortcut(Uri uri) {

  String rowId = uri.getLastPathSegment();
  String[] columns = new String[] {
      BaseColumns._ID,
      DictionaryDatabase.KEY_WORD,
      DictionaryDatabase.KEY_DEFINITION,
      DictionaryDatabase.KEY_EXAMPLE,
      SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_SHORTCUT_ID,
      SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA_ID};

  return mDictionary.getWord(rowId, columns);
}

@Override
public String getType(Uri uri) {
    switch (sURIMatcher.match(uri)) {
        case SEARCH_WORDS:
            return WORDS_MIME_TYPE;
        case GET_WORD:
            return DEFINITION_MIME_TYPE;
        case SEARCH_SUGGEST:
            return SearchManager.SUGGEST_MIME_TYPE;
        case REFRESH_SHORTCUT:
            return SearchManager.SHORTCUT_MIME_TYPE;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URL " + uri);
    }
}

@Override
public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}

@Override
public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}

@Override
public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}

}
```

SenseDictionary.Java (the Main Activity)

```
public class SenseDictionary extends Activity {

private TextView mTextView;
private ListView mListView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    handleIntent(getIntent());
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    handleIntent(intent);
}

private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
    if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Intent wordIntent = new Intent(this, WordActivity.class);
        wordIntent.setData(intent.getData());
        startActivity(wordIntent);
    } else if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        showResults(query);
    }
}

private void showResults(String query) {

    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(DictionaryProvider.CONTENT_URI, null, null,
                            new String[] {query}, null);

    if (cursor == null) {
        mTextView.setText(getString(R.string.no_results, new Object[] {query}));
    } else {
        int count = cursor.getCount();
        String countString = getResources().getQuantityString(R.plurals.search_results,
                                count, new Object[] {count, query});
        mTextView.setText(countString);

        String[] from = new String[] { DictionaryDatabase.KEY_WORD,
                                       DictionaryDatabase.KEY_DEFINITION,
                                       DictionaryDatabase.KEY_EXAMPLE};

        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.word,
                               R.id.definition,
                               R.id.example};

        SimpleCursorAdapter words = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                                      R.layout.result, cursor, from, to);
        mListView.setAdapter(words);

        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent wordIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WordActivity.class);
                Uri data = Uri.withAppendedPath(DictionaryProvider.CONTENT_URI,
                                                String.valueOf(id));
                wordIntent.setData(data);
                startActivity(wordIntent);
            }
        });
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
    }

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.search:
            onSearchRequested();
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}
}
```

WordActivity

```
public class WordActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.word);

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, null, null, null, null);

    if (cursor == null) {
        finish();
    } else {
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        TextView word = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.word);
        TextView definition = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.definition);
        TextView example = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.example);

        int wIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DictionaryDatabase.KEY_WORD);
        int dIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DictionaryDatabase.KEY_DEFINITION);
        int eIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DictionaryDatabase.KEY_EXAMPLE);

        word.setText(cursor.getString(wIndex));
        definition.setText(cursor.getString(dIndex));
        example.setText(cursor.getString(eIndex));
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
    }

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.search:
            onSearchRequested();
            return true;
        case android.R.id.home:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, SenseDictionary.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Nobody can help me???

Answer (score 1):

I would like to help you, but there are some issues.

First: You only posted the question an hour ago. In general, the stackoverflow community is not eagerly waiting for the next question to come in. You'll have to be patient.

Second: You've only posted your program. There may be someone out there who's willing to go through it step by step to figure out the problem, and I wish him or her luck, but I'd hesitate to do it. stackoverflow isn't my full-time job, so I can't spend 15-20 minutes just figuring out what (if anything) your program does.
It's not a simple program. You have a database, a content provider, and two activities.

Third: Your program doesn't have a single comment. Makes it even harder to debug.

Fourth: You said "I've tried to create a new table column: KEY_EXAMPLE. But it doesn't work." What happens? Why do you think it's not working? What do you expect it to do?

stackoverflow "works" when you have a specific question or problem that has you stumped. It works the worst when you ask, in essence, "fix my program for me".

Having said all this, I'll venture an off-the-wall guess: Did you run this app before and create a previous version of the database? If so, I don't see any place that you're deleting the previous version. You won't be able to create a new version, including the new column, until you delete the old version. You can do this in Settings > Apps > *appname* > Clear Data, or you can put it into the program itself.

Good luck!